# Current consumption calculation + Full wave Bridge rectifier

Tags: current, bridge-rectifier, power-consumption

I am facing to calculate the current consumption in a segment of a circuit as shown in the picture below.I have used the formula (showed in the picture) without considering the impedance of the capacitor C1. I have just considered the resistors components. Can any one tell me if the formula that I have done is correct to determine the current consumption.[image]
Best regards,

Comment: Pro tip: Hold Alt while right clicking on V1 in your schematic.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand your answer. Is my question well explained ?

Comment: Yes. My pro tip is however to use the built-in tools of LTspice to get your power consumption value.

Comment: @winny: Thanks for your answer. However, using Ltspice to determine the value of current consumption is relatively simple. But my question is how to detreminate by calculation the value of current. And do I have to consider the impedence of capacitor or not in the calculation

Comment: Oh! That won't be so easy due to several non-linearities. Is this homework?

Comment: @winny: Due to the non-linearities, that's why I have a doubt of calculation method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL:DR Answer

Since the cap is across source Vac and not Vdc out, it is a rectified DC Voltage but no storage so the voltage is just a rectified sine but the current is **not rectified as shown.**  (Looks like an drawing error)

### We expect Ipk ~ 320V/50k= 6.x mA  (Peak current)

Yes, you include Cap impedance, Zc=-j /2pifC =<s>-j318</s> -j31.8 kOhms shunting the 2nd term in the denominator, resulting in a phasor current.

With Vpk(AC)/Vf (diode) ratio being so small, you can neglect this, which only causes a small apparent crossover distortion of +/-1.2V in the current.

You can compute Thevenin equivalent voltage and source Zs’  (at Bridge then ignore it) for the AC analysis, then load current is V’/100k+(V’-Vzt)/100k for some threshold voltage Vzk since it is drawing a few mA where the ZK Zener Knee Voltage is rated in the datasheet.

How to do step 1? Like any serial-shunt divider, except use Zc=-j /2pifC

[image: schematic]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICURQ.png) )

Don't forget to add 0V symbol to DC output (-)=GND as I did.... to indicate V' properly

### [**Simulation**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000024999999999999998%200.625470095193633%2050%205%2048%0Av%20-80%20320%20-80%2048%200%201%2050%20325%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2048%2048%20224%2048%200%0Aw%20224%2048%20224%20112%200%0Ad%20224%20112%20288%20176%203%20default%0Ad%20224%20240%20288%20176%203%20default%0Ad%20160%20176%20224%20112%203%20default%0Ad%20160%20176%20224%20240%203%20default%0Aw%20224%20240%20224%20320%200%0Aw%20224%20320%20112%20320%200%0Aw%20160%20176%20160%20272%200%0Aw%20464%20176%20512%20176%202%0Aw%20464%20272%20512%20272%200%0Ax%20403%20164%20433%20167%204%2016%20load%0Ap%2048%2048%2048%20320%201%201%0Ap%2048%2048%2048%20256%201%204%0Aw%20112%20320%2048%20320%200%0Ap%2048%2096%2048%20320%201%203%0Ag%20464%20272%20464%20304%200%0Ap%20560%20256%20560%20272%201%203%0Ap%20560%20176%20560%20240%201%204%0Ap%20560%20208%20560%20272%201%201%0Aw%2048%20256%2048%20320%200%0Aw%2048%20192%2048%20320%200%0Ap%2048%2048%2048%20192%201%202%0Aw%2048%2048%2048%2096%200%0Ap%20560%20176%20560%20192%201%202%0Aw%20560%20192%20560%20272%200%0Aw%20512%20272%20560%20272%200%0Aw%20512%20176%20560%20176%200%0Aw%20560%20240%20560%20272%200%0Aw%20560%20176%20560%20208%200%0Aw%20560%20176%20560%20256%200%0Aw%2048%2048%20-16%2048%200%0Aw%2048%20320%20-16%20320%200%0A370%20400%20272%20160%20272%201%201%0Ar%20400%20224%20400%20272%200%2010000%0A403%20272%20-272%20432%20-128%200%200_8_0_4354_640_0.1_0_2_0_3%0Ar%20-80%2048%20-16%2048%200%201000%0Ar%20-80%20320%20-16%20320%200%201000%0Ac%20-16%2048%20-16%20320%200%201e-7%20253.5949505210564%0Aw%20-80%20320%20-192%20320%200%0Aw%20-192%2048%20-192%2096%200%0Ap%20-192%2048%20-192%20192%201%202%0Aw%20-192%20192%20-192%20320%200%0Aw%20-192%20256%20-192%20320%200%0Ap%20-192%2096%20-192%20320%201%203%0Ap%20-192%2048%20-192%20256%201%204%0Ap%20-192%2048%20-192%20320%201%201%0Aw%20-192%2048%20-80%2048%200%0Ar%20464%20176%20464%20224%200%20100000%0Ar%20512%20176%20512%20224%200%20100000%0A370%20288%20176%20464%20176%201%201%0A403%20272%2016%20432%20128%200%2051_8_0_21249_80_0.0125_0_2_51_3%0Aw%20512%20224%20512%20272%200%0A34%20default-zener6.2%200%201.7143528192810002e-7%2015%202%206.2%0Az%20464%20272%20464%20224%202%20default-zener6.2%0Aw%20400%20224%20464%20224%202%0Aw%20400%20272%20464%20272%200%0A403%20272%20-112%20432%200%200%2010_8_0_4866_320_0.1_0_2_10_3%0A403%20400%20304%20528%20368%200%2055_8_0_4354_10_0.1_0_2_55_3%0A)

[image]

Gnd symbol=0V and is **not** earth GND which is connected to Neutral at source.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I m not sure that I understand very well your meaning. So can you tell plz what modification does I have to do in the formula that I done to obtain the correct value of current. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, However What's the value of V'. Is it Vin ?? and why you neglect R1 and R2 ? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Compare VIn with I to see  effect of cap. On phase shift or phasor current. V’ is Across C with diode + R removed such that the Thevenin equiv is V’+ Z’ where Z’ is low 200//Zc. this depend how accurate you wish to compute sine current vs Vin sine voltage. then you apply load in my answer as another divider ratio

Comment: 200 //Zc : How you have calculate the value of 200 ? Thanks.

Comment: Short memory oops 2K//-j318k

Comment: Sunnyskyguy EE75: you mean Z'= 2K//-j318K ?

Comment: Corrected: Z'=2k//-j31.8k [Ω]  You are measuring primary current, while secondary is rectified. Experience comes from correcting your own mistakes before someone else. Good for you.   Lack of concentration with my feet up drinking coffee, makes my 40yrs experience look bad. (lol)

Comment: Do you need a quick simulation?

Comment: Sunnyskyguy EE75: I thank you for your explanation. Yes I want that you do to me a quick simulation to understand much more. Thanks

Comment: ok.................

Comment: If you are too lazy to comment dont' vote -1

Comment: @ Sunnyskyguy EE75: Thanks for the great simulation. It's not me who vote -1. Otherwise I didn't understand how to calculate the current through R1/R2 (around 11.5 mA peak by simulation)

Comment: And when we use the thevenin theorem and convert the impedance to (Z'C + ZL) we found a current equal to around 6.mA peak for the hole circuit.

Comment: I show 6.158 mApk  ( I know who the  -1  brain deads are)

Comment: Sorry Yes 6.158mA. So is there any explanation for this difference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But whole source current is 11.5

Comment: OK. But how you obtain the value of 11.5mA ? I m really curious to proof this value by calculation.

Comment: Like I said you can take out bridge for AC model then adjust for diode error Vf https://tinyurl.com/yyeueru5  which is fuzzy in image

Comment: Thanks for the simulation. I cannot understand how you can replace the bridge rectifier by a capacitor (10µF) ?? and my question is there any theory for your explanation.

Comment: The input AC current still alternates and the diode switch is low loss (0.7V)  THINK HOW IT WORKS, explore each signal. I gave you the tool to answer your own questions.It can all be explained by fundamental Thevenin, OHm's Law and Physics of each part.

Comment: @ Sunnyskyguy EE75: Thanks for your explanation. I will explore each signal to determine the fundamental law of the value showed by simulation.

Comment: You can also add any trace Docked to bottom or undocked and move, on screen to any Node V or any line or part for V,I,P,spectrum max,RMS,Min or duplicate existing PRobes and drag anywhere. Undo/Redo and much more with trace sample rate (options>other options)  Scope trace is autoscale and you can choose MAX for full scale